# Is there a dialog/menu editor control in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I'm trying to write a .NET GUI app that will allow custom editing of the resources in Visual Studio C++ projects (`.rc` files). So I'm wondering if there's a .NET control that will allow:

A. Displaying and editing of the dialog windows (like Visual Studio has):

[image]

B. Menu editor:

[image]

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The closest built-in thing is the `PropertyGrid` control (that has the exact property sheet that you edit in VS), that may come in handy, but not your exact requirement.

Comment: SharpDevelop has the relevant designers you wanted as it is a Visual Studio clone, https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop

Comment: @LexLi: that looks very promising. Thanks.